# Chromedriver for Chrome 77 is supposed to support headless downloads, but download still doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

On the ChromeDriver downloads page (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) it lists "Support to save file downloads in headless mode" as a feature for ChromeDriver supporting Chrome 77.

I installed Chrome 77 (https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/) and downloaded the new ChromeDriver. I'm on a Mac with Mojave 10.14.5.

However, the download does not get saved when I am in headless mode. If I do not use headless mode, the file saves as expected.

According to my logging I am successfully clicking the "Download" just like in non-headless mode:

> Element found with locator: //button[contains(text(), 'Download All as
>   CSV')] and locator type: xpath
>
> Clicked on element with locator: //button[contains(text(), 'Download
>   All as CSV')] locatorType: xpath

but nothing gets downloaded. There are no errors or exceptions.

I have tried implementing various workarounds including this one https://github.com/shawnbutton/PythonHeadlessChrome/blob/master/driver_builder.py without any luck, both before updating Chrome/ChromeDriver and after.

All my other tests work fine in headless mode, just not the download.

I am wondering if anyone else has had success with the new ChromeDriver, or if anyone has other strategies for me to try - perhaps there is further logging/debugging I can add in to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: Code trials? HTML? any error?

Comment: There are no exceptions or errors. I am not sure what you mean by code trials. Unfortunately I cannot share HTML as it's within a proprietary application.

Comment: For Mac  there is open issue with chromedriver https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=979847 . It only work on window and Linux.

Comment: you still have to enable downloads in headless mode

Comment: @RahulL ah thank you when I set .setDownloadBehavior it does crash. OK, I suppose we are blocked by this issue. Thank you!